# Showing P(A) not a subset of A, for all A

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given only the following axioms:

-Separation (if A is set, and B a partial class of A, then B is a set)

-Pairing (the class {a,b} is a set)

-Union (∀ A a set, ∪A is a set)

-Infinity ({x | x ∈ ℕ} is a set)

Prove that ∀ A a set, P(A) = {B | B ⊆ A} ⊈ A

The question hints to use Russell’s paradox

To try by contradiction means:
∃ A a set such that P(A) ⊆ A

then A ∈ A
which doesn’t lead to contradictions using those axioms.

Thanks for the help,

Comment: Your definition of separation is unusual. Why "partial class?" But I can confirm that the only axiom of set theory you will need is the usual separation axiom (as in ZFC). And you will need to invoke it only once, i.e. when you construct B (as in Hunter's outline).

Comment: @DanChristensen is the phrasing sub-class correct here? (all is meant is that each element of the class is an element of the set)

Comment: It just isn't necessary in this case to bring classes into this discussion. A ZFC-like separation axiom with no mention of classes is quite adequate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that P(A) is a subset of A. Then every subset of A is an element of A.

Let B be the set of elements of A which do not contain themselves. Since $B$ is a subset of $A$, it is an element of $A$, by assumption. Then $B$ contains itself if and only if it does not contain itself; contradiction.

Comment: Morally: the axiom of comprehension (which you are calling separation) allows us to avoid Russell's paradox by only considering subsets of given sets. Thus we can't say "consider the set of all sets that don't contain themselves" because our axioms didn't allow a "set of all sets." But we can still very well say "consider the set of all elements of some $A$ that don't contain themselves" which will only allow a contradiction if $A$ is sufficiently wacky. The assumption $\mathcal{P}(A) \subset A$ allows us to construct a sufficiently wacky set.

Comment: er, implies that $A$ is sufficiently wacky. (sorry, not allowed to edit old comment.)

Comment: Perfect! I missed the fact we can construct this by separation.